# Java Constructor Injection

Tags: java, constructor, dependency-injection, instantiation, constructor-injection

Let's say I have a class `resources` which instantiates all of my OpenGL / Java game objects and I then pass these via constructor to my Scene class (which requires them), like so (simplified example).....

```
public class Resources {

    Hero hero;
    Enemy enemy;
    MenuButtons mainMenuButtons;
    Background background;
    Scene mainMenu;

    public void createObjects(){

        hero = new Hero();
        enemy = new Enemy();
        mainMenuButtons = new MenuButtons();
        background = new Background();
        mainMenu = new Scene(hero, enemy, mainMenuButtons, background);
    }
}
```

Obviously my Scene's constructor would need to take 4 arguments like so:

```
public class MainMenu implements Scene {

    hero Hero;
    enemy Enemy;
    mainMenuButtons MenuButtons;
    background Background;

    public MainMenu(Hero hero, Enemy enemy, MainMenuButtons mainMenuButtons, Background background){

        this.hero = hero;
        this.enemy = enemy;
        this.mainMenuButtons = mainMenuButtons;
        this.background = background;
    }
}
```

As more objects are required, the constructor grows ever longer.  Now let's say I do something like the following instead:

```
public class MainMenu implements Scene {

    Resources resources;

    public MainMenu(Resources resources){

        this.hero = resources.hero;
        this.enemy = resources.enemy;
        this.mainMenuButtons = resources.mainMenuButtons;
        this.background = resources.background;
    }

}
```

Both options would allow me to use objects within my mainMenuScene like so:

```
hero.move();
```

The 2nd seems to be little neater as the constructor will never need to take any additional arguments. *However* as far as I can recall, I've never really seen any examples like this.  Is this a valid technique?  Would I run into an problems using it?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I may be mis-understanding, but I though Java was pass-by-value, the value for objects (as opposed to primitives), being a pointer to the object, not the object itself? If so, how can passing one object be worse than passing 3?  Obviously my understanding in this area is wrong - thanks!

Comment: You are correct Zippy, you will only get a copy of the reference, not a copy of the whole object.

Comment: With [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted) what you're describing is called a `Module`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:-**Yes the technique is valid and it should work fine.**

Longer part:-
I would like to suggest two design approaches to consider

The [essence](http://www.hillside.net/plop/plop98/final_submissions/P10.pdf) pattern

The [fluent](http://java.dzone.com/news/factories-builders-and-fluent-) interface pattern

These are both similar in intent.

Also the builder pattern can be helpful. We see it many times using hibernate. For your class it could like below:-

```
public class mainMenu implements Scene {

    private Hero hero;
    private Enemy enemy;
    private MenuButtons mainMenuButtons;
    private Background background;

    public mainMenu setHero(Hero hero){this.hero = hero; return this}
    public mainMenu setEnemy(Enemy enemy){this.enemy = enemy; return this}
    public mainMenu setMainMenuButtons(MenuButtons mainMenuButtons){this.mainMenuButtons = mainMenuButtons; return this}
    public mainMenu setBackground(Background background){this.background = background; return this}


}
```

And then you could create objects using chaining something like below:-

```
mainMenu main =new mainMenu().
setHero(new Hero()).
setEnemy(new Enemy()).
setMainMenuButtons(new MainMenuButtons()).
setBackground(new Background());
```

P.S. Even if you don't want to use above patterns I recommend three changes or habits.
1. Class name start with uppercase alphabet and
2. A convention of organizing the arguments alphabetically.
3. Probably you want to set acces level of the members to private.

Comment: I can add to your two points that you most liekyl watn to set the acces level of the members to private.

Comment: @Emz got you.. Thanks.. I made them private.. My bad copied the members as it is from questions

Comment: Thank @VirajNalawade for the example code and the links, they're very helpful. Quick question re the builder pattern. Can I use it if the object I'm creating needs to be available in multiple scenes? I mean the same object, not a new copy of it. If not would another approach be better in my situation? Thanks

Comment: @Zippy you are welcome.. and yes you can use this method when want the object to be available in multiple scenes.. We are not creating new object here..

Comment: Thanks @VirajNakawade so just to confirm, when we run mainMenu.setHero(new Hero()), we aren't actually creating a new hero? The 'new' keyword is throwing me here, so for another scene I would run scene2.setHero(new Hero())? Am I getting that right, where do I call setHero(new Hero) from, from the scene I created as I've just shown? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zippy I got you. 1.when we run _mainMenu.setHero(new Hero())_ we are creating new hero in this line. 2.So what you can do is _Hero hero =new Hero();_ and then do _scene1.setHero(hero)_ and _scene2.setHero(hero)_. So in this way you shared a hero object in multiple scenes and do not get new copy of the whole object.Same applies for _enemy_ and others. 3.You can call setHero at time of constructing/creating _mainMenu_ objects.Or you can use call setHero just in time before use.The advantage is you use chaining here and do _setHero(hero).setEnemy(enemy)_ . Have I answered your questions??

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, @VirajNalawade appreciate it!.  And I will also have a proper read through the links you provided. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I like it.  Instead of `Resources`, I like to call it an `ApplicationContext` and use the same way.

I've been critized for creating a ["God Object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).  I disagree with this.  As long as the ApplicationContext is thin and only holds objects, but doesn't know anything about them (call any methods), then it's fine.  It could be replaced by a List or Map, except I like the additional type checking.

See the [Service Locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) pattern for another way of doing this.

Comment: If you make sure that the so called God Object doens't have accesors to any of it properties then I guess it is fine. It is a bit dangeroues allowing one object to hold all the data however. Maybe a Singleton solution to the specific data might be viable? Like an intern database?

Comment: Absolutely @marcspace, it simply instantiates the objects. It doesn't actually hold any logic for them per-se, all of that is within the objects themselves. It does contain some accessors currently, but they can be removed (they will no longer be required as I'll be able to access the objects directly using this method) thanks for the suggestions too Emz.